# How to add jupyter scripts to PATH

Tags: installation, path, jupyter-notebook

I'm always struggling in adding path.

After installing jupyter notebook, it warns

```
The scripts jupyter, jupyter-migrate and jupyter-troubleshoot are installed in '/Users/gangzhao/Library/Python/3.7/bin' which is not on PATH.
  Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.
  The scripts jupyter-kernel, jupyter-kernelspec and jupyter-run are installed in '/Users/gangzhao/Library/Python/3.7/bin' which is not on PATH.
  Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.
  The script jsonschema is installed in '/Users/gangzhao/Library/Python/3.7/bin' which is not on PATH.
  Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.
  The script jupyter-trust is installed in '/Users/gangzhao/Library/Python/3.7/bin' which is not on PATH.
  Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.
  The script pygmentize is installed in '/Users/gangzhao/Library/Python/3.7/bin' which is not on PATH.
  Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.
  The script jupyter-nbconvert is installed in '/Users/gangzhao/Library/Python/3.7/bin' which is not on PATH.
  Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.
  The scripts iptest, iptest3, ipython and ipython3 are installed in '/Users/gangzhao/Library/Python/3.7/bin' which is not on PATH.
  Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.
  The scripts jupyter-bundlerextension, jupyter-nbextension, jupyter-notebook and jupyter-serverextension are installed in '/Users/gangzhao/Library/Python/3.7/bin' which is not on PATH.
  Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.
  The script jupyter-console is installed in '/Users/gangzhao/Library/Python/3.7/bin' which is not on PATH. 
  Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.
```

I find a really [good post](http://good%20post) about adding directory to PYTHONPATH.

But I still can't figure it out.

```
export PYTHONPATH="${PYTHONPATH}:/my/other/path"
```

I'm confusing about what is `PYTHONPATH` and what is `/my/other/path`

Answer (score 2):

**OS : Windows Server 2019
Tool: VS Code**

**Warning Message after installing Jupyter using "pip install notebook" :**

WARNING: The script send2trash.exe is installed in 'C:\Users\Username\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\Scripts' which is not on PATH.
Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.

**Error after running "jupyter notebook" to initiate the notebook:**

jupyter : The term 'jupyter' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the
name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1

- jupyter notebook
- ```
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (jupyter:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
  ```

**Fix:**

run the command "python -m pip install jupyter" in the vs code terminal.

---

This worked for me, Hope this fixes your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should try using the builtin jupyter notebook available when install Anaconda. I have never had this kind of problem when I installed Jupyter via Anaconda.

Comment: This is certainly a way to avoid the problem. But I would rather to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you got a fix for this already, but i too have reproduced the same error recently while building jupyter on the raspberry pi zero W, managed a solution so thought id post it.

My connection is ssh through putty

First, i installed jupyter normally through pip3 and received multiple path errors on the bins as well. Confirmed this because running any `jupyter` commands would return not found.

My solution was to just make a service, you can do this by first finding where the jupyter binary is: `which jupyter-lab`.
This should return the path to the binary and should be very similar to: `/home/pi/.local/bin/jupyter-lab`. Record this information because you will need it to create a file in `/etc/systemd/system/`

Create the service:

```
sudo nano /etc/systemd/system/jupyter.service
```

Populate the file with:

```
[Unit]
    Description=Jupyter Lab
[Service]
    Type=simple
    PIDFile=/run/jupyter.pid
    ExecStart=/bin/bash -c "/home/pi/.local/bin/jupyter-lab --ip="0.0.0.0" --no-browser --notebook-dir=/home/pi/notebooks"
    User=pi
    Group=pi
    WorkingDirectory=/home/pi/notebooks
    Restart=always
    RestartSec=10
[Install]
    WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Notice `ExecStart=` is where you put the path of the binary that was found earlier. This is also where you configure the parameters for jupyter-lab, including IP and notebook directory. As a note, i did have my directory set up for this.

Next we can run this service easily:

```
sudo systemctl start jupyter.service
```

Or stop it:

```
sudo systemctl stop jupyter.service
```

Want to make the service start on every boot:

```
sudo systemctl enable jupyter.service
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
```

Check the service status:

```
sudo systemctl status jupyter.service
```

This will give you useful service information about the ServerApp running from jupyter. The token and URL to connect to your notebook will be displayed here also.

Hope this helps and solves any issues!